# why does cordova app hang on launch in xcode with cpu 100%?

Tags: xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins

cordova version 5.0.0
xcode version 7.3

i have a cordova app (with ember.js) that, when launched, hangs on launch in xcode.  this does not happen every time, it is intermittent.  when it does happen, the cpu in cordova hovers around 100%.  the app is non responsive; taps on buttons do nothing.

below is the system log, and listed here are the plugins being used.  how can i begin to debug this?  i can't connect to the app with safari debugger; the app is listed in the develop menu but the debugger is blank.

plugins:

```
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" spec="1.5.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.1.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="1.2.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="1.2.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-appsee" spec="2.1.55" />
  <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="1.0.8" />
  <plugin name="sk.kcorp.cordova.ios-security" spec="https://github.com/robertklein/cordova-ios-security.git" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="https://github.com/sovolve/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" spec="2.0.1" />
  <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />
  <preference name="android-configChanges" value="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="~1.4.1">
    <variable name="APP_ID" value="1650330931884748" />
    <variable name="APP_NAME" value="Wonder" />
  </plugin>
  <plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="~1.11.2" />
```

last chunk of system log (there's a lot more, too much to fit here)

http://pastebin.com/7HzgP4eB

Answer (score 0):

Which version of cordova-ios are you running? Version 4.0.0 of cordova-ios had a bug which caused 100% CPU usage on launch (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10276 for more information). This has been fixed since 4.1.0. You can check by running this command:

```
cordova platform version
```

To update to the latest version, run:

```
 cordova platform update ios
```